# Undesired results using `STR_TO_DATE` in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, str-to-date

I sort a query result by using:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(table1.date, '%Y%m%d'); -- the format of `date` is `Ymd` without delimiter.
```

However, the result is undesired:

```
20150508
20150514
20150525
20150514
20150515
20150522
20150525
20150529
20150605
20150612
20150619
```

---

Sorry for my carefulness. I use the shell command `sort` (`./batch_queries.sh | cut -f 3-9,12- | sort | uniq -c`) to sort the query result, leading to such a undsired result.

Comment: Why convert in the `order by` clause - the result is the same and faster if you don't convert

Comment: @juergend I would like to sort the query result by date.

Comment: But since you store it like this `20150619` it is already in a perfectly orderable form. just do `ORDER BY table1.date`

Comment: @juergend I mistakenly assume I store `data` as **VARCHAR**. I checked it just now, it is  *\`date\` VARCHAR(8)*

Comment: Even for alphanumeric ordering the result should be fine. And you actually should just change the type to date.

Comment: @juergend Sorry for my carefulness. I use the shell command `sort` to sort the query result, `./batch_queries.sh | cut -f 3-9,12- | sort | uniq -c`. Should I remove this question?